# Not receiving Extras from sendBroadcast

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a MainClass that registers a BroadcastReceiver and overrides its onReceive() method

```
        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
            Log.w("MyApp","RICEVUTO MESSAGGIO BROADCAST: "+intent.getStringExtra("com.example.avis.NUOVANEWS"));
            Log.w("MyApp","Intent TOSTRING "+intent.toString());


        }

    };
    this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,  new IntentFilter("nuovanewsavis"));
```

In the class NewsService, when a new news is found, i broadcast a new message. Here's the code

```
              Intent intento=new Intent("nuovanewsavis");
          intent.setAction("nuovanewsavis");
          intent.putExtra("com.example.avis.NUOVANEWS", "Nuova notizia");

          this.sendBroadcast(intento);
```

The MainClass cannot get the extra: if i try to read it through getStringExtra i get a null.
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there has a typo...your using `intent` instead of `intento` when putting extra.

```
      Intent intento = new Intent("nuovanewsavis");
      intento.setAction("nuovanewsavis");
      intento.putExtra("com.example.avis.NUOVANEWS", "Nuova notizia");

      this.sendBroadcast(intento);
```

Comment: uhm.. intento is just the Intent name, how can it affect the App? I should get a compile error

Comment: you create an `Intent` object with name `intento` but you assigned your `Extra` to an `Intent` object named `intent`. is `intento` and `intent` are same?